# Can not set up routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

By following Steps to implement routing on Official sites i have set up some routes for my new ng2 application but i can not make it work.

My Routes Files.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SchoolComponent } from './school/school.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

// Route Configuration
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'users', component: UserComponent },
    { path: 'schools', component: SchoolComponent },
    { path: 'admins', component: AdminComponent },
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Module File

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SchoolComponent } from './school/school.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    SchoolComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

When i try to access routes i got these errors in console

```
    error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UserComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UserComponent'
```

I can not find out what i am doing wrong. Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Seems to be you navigating to "user" instead configured route "users".

Comment: ah sorry now i am getting this error error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UserComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UserComponent'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot find primary outlet means you haven't added **`router-outlet`** to **`HTML`** 
. you just need to added it in **`HTML`** like this,

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```